# TypeScript type assertion if my object is empty and hasn't the interface keys

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface:

```
interface User { 
    name: string,
    age: number
}
```

function:

```
function test(user: User): void { 

}
```

and empty object created with the interface:

```
const user1 = <User>{};
test(user1);
```

So I don't understand why my code is compiling, because my empty object hasn't the interface keys.
How can I prevent compiling if my object is empty and hasn't the interface keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<User>{}` is type assertion, which basically means you're telling TypeScript that "Yeah, it is a `User` alright, don't tell me otherwise". Therefore TypeScript doesn't report any error.

If you want TypeScript to catch your coding error, in this case you should use

```
const user1: User = {};
```

instead, and you'll get the error you're asking for. For more information, see [this page](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/type-assertion).

Comment: Yes, but if I will write const user1 = <User>{z: 4}; I will get an error, so why if I use an empty object it doesn't show me error?

Comment: This is because in this case the neither types `User` and `{z: number}` overlap the other one. Overlapping is necessary for using type assertion.